# My D3js treemap chart is ou of my div when i zoom on it

Tags: javascript, symfony, d3.js

I have a small problem with my D3 treemap chart. When i click on element my chart zoom on this element but the chart gone out of my div. I want the chart stay in my block cardnavigation
Here is my chart code:

```js
function showtreemap(data, target) {


  //console.log(d3.schemeCategory20c)
  const tileWidth = 100
  const tileHeight = 100
  const tileScale = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.schemeAccent)



  var tileXscale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, tileWidth]).range([0, tileWidth])
  var tileYscale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, tileHeight]).range([0, tileHeight])

  var div = d3.select(target)
  //var div = $(target);


  var treemap = d3.treemap()
    .size([tileWidth, tileHeight])

  var root = d3.hierarchy(data)
    // For equal representation
    .sum(function(d) {
      return d.value ? 1 : 0
    })



  // .sum((d) => d.value)
  var tree = treemap(root)

  var cells = div.selectAll(".node")
    .data(root.descendants())
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return "node level-" + d.depth
    })
    .attr("title", function(d) {
      return d.data.name
    })

  cells.style("left", function(d) {
      return tileXscale(d.x0) + "%"
    })
    .style("top", function(d) {
      return tileYscale(d.y0) + "%"
    })
    .style("width", function(d) {
      return tileXscale(d.x1) - tileXscale(d.x0) + "%"
    })
    .style("height", function(d) {
      return tileYscale(d.y1) - tileYscale(d.y0) + "%"
    })
    .style("background-color", function(d) {
      while (d.depth > 2) {
        d = d.parent
      }
      return tileScale(d.data.name)
    })
    .on("click", zoom)
    .append("p")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.name ? d.data.name : "---"
    })

  var parent = d3.select(".up")
    .datum(root)
    .on("click", zoom)

  // The zooming behavior was based off of here: https://codepen.io/znak/pen/qapRkQ?editors=0010
  function zoom(d) {
    var currentDepth = d.depth
    parent.datum(d.parent || root)
    tileXscale.domain([d.x0, d.x1])
    tileYscale.domain([d.y0, d.y1])

    var t = d3.transition()
      .duration(800)
      .ease(d3.easeCubicOut)

    cells.transition(t)
      .style("left", function(d) {
        return tileXscale(d.x0) + "%"
      })
      .style("top", function(d) {
        return tileYscale(d.y0) + "%"
      })
      .style("width", function(d) {
        return tileXscale(d.x1) - tileXscale(d.x0) + "%"
      })
      .style("height", function(d) {
        return tileYscale(d.y1) - tileYscale(d.y0) + "%"
      })

    // Hide this depth and above
    cells.filter(function(d) {
        return d.ancestors()
      })
      .classed("hide", function(d) {
        return d.children ? true : false
      })

    cells.filter(function(d) {
        return d.depth > currentDepth
      })
      .classed("hide", false)
  }
}
```

and here is my page code:

```html
{% extends 'layouts/base.html.twig' %} {% block title %}My IT Maps {% endblock %} {% block body %}
<!-- Begin Page Content -->
<div class="container-fluid body1">
  <!-- Page Heading -->
  <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-center mb-4">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800">Navigation</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <!-- Default Card -->
      <div class="card mb-4">
        <div class="card-header"></div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <form action="" method="post">
            <label>
                            <input id="graph" name="graph" type="radio" value="treemap" checked>Treemap
                        </label>
            <label>
                            <input id="graph" name="graph" type="radio" value="donuts">Donuts
                        </label>
            <label>
                            <input id="graph" name="graph" type="radio" value="list">List
                        </label>
            <hr>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
                <option selected>Fonctions métiers</option>
                <option>Sociétés</option>
                <option>Sites</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Default Card Example -->
      <div class="card mb-4">
        <div class="card-header">
          Sociétés
        </div>
        <div class="card-body tree">
          <div id="jstree1">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i>
                <a href="#">
                  <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon"></i>Root node 1</a>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i>
                    <a class="jstree-anchor  jstree-clicked" href="#">
                      <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon"></i>
                      <em>initially</em>
                      <strong>selected</strong>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li role="treeitem" data-jstree="{ &quot;icon&quot; : &quot;https://jstree.com/tree-icon.png&quot; }" id="j1_3" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf" aria-selected="false">
                    <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i>
                    <a class="jstree-anchor" href="#">
                      <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon jstree-themeicon-custom" style="background-image: url(https://jstree.com/tree-icon.png); background-size: auto; background-position: 50% 50%;"></i>custom icon URL</a>
                  </li>
                  <li role="treeitem" data-jstree="{ &quot;opened&quot; : true }" aria-expanded="true" id="j1_4" class="jstree-node  jstree-open" aria-selected="false">
                    <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i>
                    <a class="jstree-anchor" href="#">
                      <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon"></i>initially open
                    </a>
                    <ul role="group" class="jstree-children">
                      <li role="treeitem" id="j1_5" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf jstree-last">
                        <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i>
                        <a class="jstree-anchor" href="#">
                          <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon"></i>Another node
                        </a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li role="treeitem" data-jstree="{ &quot;icon&quot; : &quot;glyphicon glyphicon-leaf&quot; }" id="j1_6" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf jstree-last">
                    <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i>
                    <a class="jstree-anchor" href="#">
                      <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon glyphicon glyphicon-leaf jstree-themeicon-custom"></i>Custom icon class (bootstrap)</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li role="treeitem" id="j1_7" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf jstree-last">
                <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i>
                <a class="jstree-anchor" href="https://www.jstree.com">
                  <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon"></i>Root node 2
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Default Card Example -->
      <div class="card mb-4">
        <div class="card-header">
          Sites
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div id="jstree2">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i>
                <a href="#">
                  <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon"></i>Root node 1</a>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i>
                    <a class="jstree-anchor  jstree-clicked" href="#">
                      <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon"></i>
                      <em>initially</em>
                      <strong>selected</strong>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li role="treeitem" data-jstree="{ &quot;icon&quot; : &quot;https://jstree.com/tree-icon.png&quot; }" id="j1_3" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf" aria-selected="false">
                    <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i>
                    <a class="jstree-anchor" href="#">
                      <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon jstree-themeicon-custom" style="background-image: url(https://jstree.com/tree-icon.png); background-size: auto; background-position: 50% 50%;"></i>custom icon URL</a>
                  </li>
                  <li role="treeitem" data-jstree="{ &quot;opened&quot; : true }" aria-expanded="true" id="j1_4" class="jstree-node  jstree-open" aria-selected="false">
                    <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i>
                    <a class="jstree-anchor" href="#">
                      <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon"></i>initially open
                    </a>
                    <ul role="group" class="jstree-children">
                      <li role="treeitem" id="j1_5" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf jstree-last">
                        <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i>
                        <a class="jstree-anchor" href="#">
                          <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon"></i>Another node
                        </a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li role="treeitem" data-jstree="{ &quot;icon&quot; : &quot;glyphicon glyphicon-leaf&quot; }" id="j1_6" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf jstree-last">
                    <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i>
                    <a class="jstree-anchor" href="#">
                      <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon glyphicon glyphicon-leaf jstree-themeicon-custom"></i>Custom icon class (bootstrap)</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li role="treeitem" id="j1_7" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf jstree-last">
                <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i>
                <a class="jstree-anchor" href="https://www.jstree.com">
                  <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon"></i>Root node 2
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Default Card Example -->
      <div class="card mb-4">
        <div class="card-header">
          Fonctions métiers
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div id="jstree3">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i>
                <a href="#">
                  <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon"></i>Root node 1</a>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i>
                    <a class="jstree-anchor  jstree-clicked" href="#">
                      <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon"></i>
                      <em>initially</em>
                      <strong>selected</strong>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li role="treeitem" data-jstree="{ &quot;icon&quot; : &quot;https://jstree.com/tree-icon.png&quot; }" id="j1_3" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf" aria-selected="false">
                    <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i>
                    <a class="jstree-anchor" href="#">
                      <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon jstree-themeicon-custom" style="background-image: url(https://jstree.com/tree-icon.png); background-size: auto; background-position: 50% 50%;"></i>custom icon URL</a>
                  </li>
                  <li role="treeitem" data-jstree="{ &quot;opened&quot; : true }" aria-expanded="true" id="j1_4" class="jstree-node  jstree-open" aria-selected="false">
                    <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i>
                    <a class="jstree-anchor" href="#">
                      <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon"></i>initially open
                    </a>
                    <ul role="group" class="jstree-children">
                      <li role="treeitem" id="j1_5" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf jstree-last">
                        <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i>
                        <a class="jstree-anchor" href="#">
                          <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon"></i>Another node
                        </a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li role="treeitem" data-jstree="{ &quot;icon&quot; : &quot;glyphicon glyphicon-leaf&quot; }" id="j1_6" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf jstree-last">
                    <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i>
                    <a class="jstree-anchor" href="#">
                      <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon glyphicon glyphicon-leaf jstree-themeicon-custom"></i>Custom icon class (bootstrap)</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li role="treeitem" id="j1_7" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf jstree-last">
                <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i>
                <a class="jstree-anchor" href="https://www.jstree.com">
                  <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon"></i>Root node 2
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <!-- Default Card Example -->
      {% block cardnavigation %}
      <div class="card" id="card-graph-treemap">
        <div class="card-header">Treemap</div>
        <div class="card-body" id="treemap">
          <nav>
            <div class="up" id="graph-btn-previous">
              <input class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" value="Précédent">
            </div>
          </nav>
          <div id="treemap-body"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card" id="card-graph-donuts">
        <div class="card-header">Donuts</div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div id="donuts-body"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card" id="card-graph-list">
        <div class="card-header">Liste</div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="panel">
              <button id="loadData" class="btn btn-default">Load Data</button>

              <table id="dataTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Children</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %} {% block javascriptsp %}
<script src="{{asset('js/lib/jquery.easing.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/lib/d3.v5.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/lib/jstree.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/jstree.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/treemap.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/donuts.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/arbo.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/datatables.min.js')}}"></script>


<script>
  function selectTreemap() {
    $('#treemap-body').empty();
    $('#card-graph-treemap').show();
    $('#card-graph-donuts').hide();
    $('#card-graph-list').hide();

    d3.json('/data/treemap').then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      showtreemap(data, "#treemap-body");
    });
  }

  function selectDonuts() {
    $('#donuts-body').empty();
    $('#card-graph-treemap').hide();
    $('#card-graph-donuts').show();
    $('#card-graph-list').hide();

    d3.json('/data/donuts').then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      donuts(data, '#donuts-body');
    });
  }

  function selectList() {
    $('#card-graph-donuts').hide();
    $('#card-graph-treemap').hide();
    $('#card-graph-list').show();

    $('#dataTable').DataTable({
      ajax: {
        url: '/data/list',
        dataSrc: 'data'
      },
      columns: [{
        data: 'name'
      }, {
        data: 'children'
      }]
    });
  }

  $("input[name='graph']").change(function() {
    var checkedValue = $("input[name='graph']:checked").val();
    switch (checkedValue) {
      case "treemap":
        selectTreemap();
        break;
      case "donuts":
        selectDonuts();
        break;
      case "list":
        selectList();
        break;
      default:
        console.error(`Unknown value for graph radio button {checkedValue}`);
    }
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    selectTreemap();
  });
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

I search for long time the solution but don't find the correct issue.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using normal `HTML` elements instead of `SVG` ones, you can just use normal CSS properties. In this case, adding `overflow: hidden;` to the container solved it for me:

```js
function showtreemap(data, target) {
  const tileWidth = 100
  const tileHeight = 100
  const tileScale = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.schemeAccent)

  var tileXscale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, tileWidth]).range([0, tileWidth])
  var tileYscale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, tileHeight]).range([0, tileHeight])

  var div = d3.select(target)

  var treemap = d3.treemap()
    .size([tileWidth, tileHeight])

  var root = d3.hierarchy(data)
    // For equal representation
    .sum(function(d) {
      return d.value ? 1 : 0
    })

  var tree = treemap(root)

  var cells = div.selectAll(".node")
    .data(root.descendants())
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return "node level-" + d.depth
    })
    .attr("title", function(d) {
      return d.data.name
    })

  cells.style("left", function(d) {
      return tileXscale(d.x0) + "%"
    })
    .style("top", function(d) {
      return tileYscale(d.y0) + "%"
    })
    .style("width", function(d) {
      return tileXscale(d.x1) - tileXscale(d.x0) + "%"
    })
    .style("height", function(d) {
      return tileYscale(d.y1) - tileYscale(d.y0) + "%"
    })
    .style("background-color", function(d) {
      while (d.depth > 2) {
        d = d.parent
      }
      return tileScale(d.data.name)
    })
    .on("click", zoom)
    .append("p")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.name ? d.data.name : "---"
    })

  var parent = d3.select(".up")
    .datum(root)
    .on("click", zoom)

  // The zooming behavior was based off of here: https://codepen.io/znak/pen/qapRkQ?editors=0010
  function zoom(d) {
    var currentDepth = d.depth
    parent.datum(d.parent || root)
    tileXscale.domain([d.x0, d.x1])
    tileYscale.domain([d.y0, d.y1])

    var t = d3.transition()
      .duration(800)
      .ease(d3.easeCubicOut)

    cells.transition(t)
      .style("left", function(d) {
        return tileXscale(d.x0) + "%"
      })
      .style("top", function(d) {
        return tileYscale(d.y0) + "%"
      })
      .style("width", function(d) {
        return tileXscale(d.x1) - tileXscale(d.x0) + "%"
      })
      .style("height", function(d) {
        return tileYscale(d.y1) - tileYscale(d.y0) + "%"
      })

    // Hide this depth and above
    cells.filter(function(d) {
        return d.ancestors()
      })
      .classed("hide", function(d) {
        return d.children ? true : false
      })

    cells.filter(function(d) {
        return d.depth > currentDepth
      })
      .classed("hide", false)
  }
}

data = {
  "name": "Portfolio",
  "children": [{
      "name": "Identity",
      "children": [{
          "name": "Auto Lenart",
          "children": [{
              "name": "Photo 1",
              "value": "cgi-1.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 2",
              "value": "cgi-2.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 3",
              "value": "cgi-3.jpg"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "PrintHouse",
          "children": [{
              "name": "Photo 1",
              "value": "photo-1.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 2",
              "value": "photo-2.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 3",
              "value": "photo-3.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 4",
              "value": "photo-4.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 5",
              "value": "photo-5.jpg"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Mertz",
          "children": [{
              "name": "Photo 1",
              "value": "epc-1.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 2",
              "value": "epc-2.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 3",
              "value": "epc-3.jpg"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Stanford",
          "children": [{
              "name": "Photo 1",
              "value": "floorplan-1.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 3",
              "value": "floorplan-2.jpg"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Web",
      "children": [{
          "name": "AEG",
          "children": [{
              "name": "Photo 1",
              "value": "litho-1.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 2",
              "value": "litho-2.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 3",
              "value": "litho-3.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 4",
              "value": "litho-4.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 5",
              "value": "litho-5.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 6",
              "value": "litho-6.jpg"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Brent",
          "children": [{
              "name": "Photo 1",
              "value": "digital-1.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 2",
              "value": "digital-2.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 3",
              "value": "digital-3.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 4",
              "value": "digital-4.jpg"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Print",
      "children": [{
          "name": "BvD",
          "children": [{
              "name": "Photo 1",
              "value": "folding-1.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 2",
              "value": "folding-2.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 3",
              "value": "folding-3.jpg"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Metalplast",
          "children": [{
              "name": "Photo 1",
              "value": "stitched-1.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 2",
              "value": "stitched-2.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 3",
              "value": "stitched-3.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 4",
              "value": "stitched-4.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 5",
              "value": "stitched-5.jpg"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Skylon",
          "children": [{
              "name": "Photo 1",
              "value": "sewn-1.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 2",
              "value": "sewn-2.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 3",
              "value": "sewn-3.jpg"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "The O2",
          "children": [{
              "name": "Photo 1",
              "value": "softback-1.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 3",
              "value": "softback-2.jpg"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Trendy",
          "children": [{
              "name": "Photo 1",
              "value": "hardback-1.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 2",
              "value": "hardback-2.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 3",
              "value": "hardback-3.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Photo 4",
              "value": "hardback-4.jpg"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

showtreemap(data, "div");
```

```css
#mydiv {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: red 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

div.node {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```